# Deleting last cell in struct based array

Tags: c, arrays, struct, cell, free

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

struct address
{
char name[80],addr[50],city[50],country[30];
int code;
} *list,*list2;

int main()
{
int epilogi,n=1,x,i;
char temp[2],temp2[2];
list=malloc(n*sizeof(struct address));
printf("Lista taxidromikon dieuthinseon\n");
printf("1. Eisagogi stoixeion\n");
printf("2. Diagrafi stoixeion\n");
printf("3. Emfanisi listas\n");
printf("4. Eksodos\n\n");
printf("Epilekste dinontas dinontas ena arithmo apo to 1 eos to 4\n");
while (epilogi!=4)
{
if (epilogi==1)
{
while (strcmp("n",temp))
{
printf("Dose onomateponimo, dieuthinsi, poli, xora kai taxidromiko kodika\n");
fgets(list[n-1].name,80,stdin);
fgets(list[n-1].addr,50,stdin);
fgets(list[n-1].city,50,stdin);
fgets(list[n-1].country,30,stdin);
scanf("%[^\n]%d%*c", &list[n-1].code);
printf("------------------------------------\n");
printf("Thelete na eisagete allo stoixeio?(Pliktrologiste y gia nai n gia oxi)\n");
fgets(temp,2,stdin);
printf("\n");
if (strcmp("n",temp))
{
n=n+1;
list=realloc(list,n*sizeof(struct address));
}
}
}
strcpy(temp,"y");
if (epilogi==2) 
{
while (strcmp("n",temp2))
{
printf("Dose taxidromiko kodika\n");
scanf("%s", &x);
for (i=0;i<n;i++)
{
if (list[i].code=x)
{
list2=malloc((n-1)*sizeof(struct address));
strcpy(list[i].name,list[n-1].name);
strcpy(list[i].addr,list[n-1].addr);
strcpy(list[i].city,list[n-1].city);
strcpy(list[i].country,list[n-1].country);
list[i].code=list[n-1].code;
}
}
for (i=0;i<n-1;i++)
{
strcpy(list2[i].name,list[i].name);
strcpy(list2[i].addr,list[i].addr);
strcpy(list2[i].city,list[i].city);
strcpy(list2[i].country,list[i].country);
list2[i].code=list[i].code;
}
free(list);
list=malloc((n-1)*sizeof(struct address));
for (i=0;i<n-1;i++)
{
strcpy(list[i].name,list2[i].name);
strcpy(list[i].addr,list2[i].addr);
strcpy(list[i].city,list2[i].city);
strcpy(list[i].country,list2[i].country);
list[i].code=list2[i].code;
}
free(list2);
n=n-1;
printf("Thelete na diagrapsete allo stoixeio?(Pliktrologiste y gia nai n gia oxi)\n");
scanf("%s", &temp2);
}
}
strcpy(temp2,"y");
if (epilogi==3)
{
for (i=0;i<n;i++)
{
printf("%s\t%s\t%s\t%s\t%d\n", list[i].name, list[i].country, list[i].city, list[i].addr, list[i].code);
}
}
printf("Dose nea epilogi\n");
scanf("%d", &epilogi);
}
return 0;
}
```

So this is a programm that gives the user 3 options 
1)Input elements
2)Delete elements
3)Show list of elements
4)Exit programm
Well my problem is located at the 2nd option. There I swap the elements that are asked to be deleted with the elements that are at the last cell of the struct address list. Then I try to use the free() function to delete the last cell(which in fact is 5 cells since it is a struct based array) but that doesnt seem to work. It doesn't compile.

[edit] So I updated my code and now I tried to delete the last cell by copying the whole "list" to "list2" except for the last cell. then i freed list and remalloced it with one less cell (n-1) copied them back from list2 and freed list2. Well the code compiles but the result are not what  i expected. The last cell is successfully deleted but for some reason one particular list input was copied to all the others. So when i go to option 3 (lets say i have 3 elements in my list and i deleted one) 2 elements appear but are the same one. Any clues?

Answer (score 0):

The code compiled for me when I changed `free(list[n-1]);` to `free(list);`. `list[n-1]` is not an array that can be deallocated - it is a struct within an array. You can only deallocate the whole array in this situation.

Btw, you should add tag C to your question, so that it is easier for others to see your question.

Answer (score 0):

Some issues:

You do not initialize temp[2] but you have a while loop

```
while (strcmp("n",temp))
```

so this may or may not work depending on what garbage is in `temp` at the start of the program.

---

this slightly complicated expression

```
scanf("%[^\n]%d%*c", &list[n-1].code);
```

could be written like this

```
char codeBuf[10];
fgets( codeBuf, sizeof(codeBuf), stdin);
list[n-1].code = atoi(codeBuf);
```

---

```
fgets(temp,2,stdin);
printf("\n");
if (strcmp("n",temp))
{ ... }
```

the expression `(strcmp("n",temp))` will never to be true because `fgets()` includes the `\n` in the buffer. You need to strip away the `\n` or just do a character comparison `if (temp[0] == 'n')`

---

Now to your issue

In order to delete an element in the array you need to either create a new buffer and copy all elements but the one you want to delete or move the subsequent entries in the array forward one step overwriting the element that you want to delete, you need then also to keep track of the original size of the buffer and realloc only when more entries than allocated will be added. Doing a free as you do it on an entry of the array will cause undefined behavior, the address you get when you allocate the array

```
list=malloc(n*sizeof(struct address));
```

is the only address you can free.

Normally when it comes this kind of problem it is easier to use a double linked list to handle the entries - inserting and freeing in the list is more straightforward IMO.

Comment: Yeah i know that double linked list is the easiest way to solve this problem but i find it too hard to understand them and therefore use them(i am kinda new to c) so I try to use "traditional" ways as much as possible. As for the complication in scanf yeah you are right i might replace the scanf using atoi later on when my program is finished but for now i leave it like that cuz it works. As for the temp issue I fixed it in a newer edition of my code(sorry for not updating) i have where I use strcpy at the start so that temp and temp2 have fixed inputs.